# AForge - incomplete list of VideoCapabilities - high frame rate

Tags: c#, webcam, frame-rate, aforge

I use AForge and C # to record video from a Logitech BRIO webcam connected via USB. I want to get about 60 fps. This camera can do such registration - other applications give such possibility for it. AForge does not allow to choose VideoCapabilities with this frame rate (list is incomplete). I mean option with AverageFrameRate=60 fps (about MaximumFrameRate AForge gives information e.g. 120 fps). These settings in other applications are not related to the low number of bits per pixel as I read in other threads.Where is the problem and how to solve it?
I understand that if VideoCapabilities has two options with the same resolution, only one of them will be shown - the one with the most bits per pixel. Is it possible to choose the second one (with fewer bits per pixel)?